# unidirectional @oneToMany without joinTable in openJpa 2

Tags: openjpa

I am trying to create a unidirectional OneToMany mapping in **openJpa 2.3.0**, but i would also want to define the column name that will hold the foreighn key on the source table. As far as i know in JPA 2.0 this can be done as follows :

```
@Entity
public class Source {


    private List<Target> targets = new ArrayList<>();


    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="SOURCE_FK")
    public List<Target> getTargets() {
        return targets;
    }
}
```

But i get the following exception :

```
 <openjpa-2.3.0-r422266:1540826 fatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: You have supplied columns for "Source.targets", but this mapping cannot have columns in this context.
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.MappingInfo.assertNoSchemaComponents(MappingInfo.java:382)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.strats.RelationToManyTableFieldStrategy.map(RelationToManyTableFieldStrategy.java:97)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.strats.RelationCollectionTableFieldStrategy.map(RelationCollectionTableFieldStrategy.java:94)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.FieldMapping.setStrategy(FieldMapping.java:146)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.RuntimeStrategyInstaller.installStrategy(RuntimeStrategyInstaller.java:82)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.FieldMapping.resolveMapping(FieldMapping.java:496)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.FieldMapping.resolve(FieldMapping.java:461)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.ClassMapping.resolveMapping(ClassMapping.java:854)
at org.apache.openjpa.meta.ClassMetaData.resolve(ClassMetaData.java:1811)
at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.processBuffer(MetaDataRepository.java:829)
at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.resolveMapping(MetaDataRepository.java:784)
at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.resolve(MetaDataRepository.java:664)
at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.getMetaDataInternal(MetaDataRepository.java:418)
at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.getMetaData(MetaDataRepository.java:389)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.persistInternal(BrokerImpl.java:2666)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.persist(BrokerImpl.java:2604)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.persist(BrokerImpl.java:2587)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.persist(BrokerImpl.java:2491)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBroker.persist(DelegatingBroker.java:1077)
at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:716)
at
```

It seems that openJpa 2.3.0 does not support the Joincolumn in unidirectional oneToMany. Is this true or am I missing something? If this is the case , is there a workaround without using join tables ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question :
 OpenJpa 2 DOES support @JoinColumn in OneToMany relationship.

As I have found [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OPENJPA-1253) there are various reasons that can lead to this exception.

In my case the problem was the false schema url in the persistence.xml

The problematic line was the followng one :

```
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">
```

Which was telling the OpenJpa to comply with JPA 1.0 specifications (JPA 1.0 does not support this annotation in OneToMany relationship but JPA 2 does)
I changed version to 2.0 and it worked fine.

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd" version="2.0">
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped a ton!